# Running script crontab Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix, sh

I have created a script that empties the Trash every 5 minutes. However, I am not able to run the script.

Here is the location of the script.

```
/Users/Ryan/Documents/trash.sh
```

Here is what my crontab looks like.

```
*/5 * * * * /Users/Ryan/Documents/trash.sh
```

Any ideas why it's not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want the Trashcan, wouldn't it be better to just disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
*/5 * * * * sh /Users/Ryan/Documents/trash.sh
```